# How can I get average of value in list of lists and add it to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to get the average value of a list of records

```
# value of ids
id=xyz.domain.com response_time=10 
id=xyz.domain.biz response_time=20
id=xyz.domain.com response_time=20
id=xyz.domain.co response_time=10
id=abc.domain.com response_time=100
id=xyz.domain.com response_time=10
id=xyz.domain.com response_time=10
```

and display some info in the following way:

```
xyz.domain.com
  count = 4
  avg_response_time = 12.5
  mode_response_time = 10
  median_response_time = 10
```

My approach was to get unique ids in the list and get the following info

- get a count of them,
- average of the response times

```py
#lets say we read the values from a file and store it in logs list
content = open("logs.txt", 'r')

logs = []
logs_dict = {}

for line in content:
    logs.append(line)
      
for log in logs:
    log = log.split(' ')
    id = log[0].split('=')[1]
    response_time = log[1].split('=')[1]

# get count using dictionary
if id in logs_dict:
    logs_dict[id] += 1
else:
    logs_dict[id] = 1
```

To get other values like `average, median` I think we need a list of values in the dictionary mapped to the ID.
How can we solve this efficiently and any tips on doing this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that your shared code contains a typo / syntax error (the names of the dicts don't match) and doesn't actually do what you expect it to (it only creates a single entry in the dictionary, due to an indentation error). Once you have the data in the dictionary, what have you thought of to compute an average or a median? How would you compute one in general, and how would you apply that to values in a dict - have you tried anything?

Comment: got it thank you

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please either delete the question if you're no longer interested in answers, or post the solution if you have a better one than the ones suggested by others (and accept it)

Answer (score 2):

You could store the results of your log calls in a dictionary mapping the domain names to a list of ping values. If you use a `defaultdict`, you can simply append each ping without having to check for existence of the dictionary keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

log_dict = defaultdict(list)

for line in open("logs.txt", "r"):
    # ... processing into id and response_time values here
    log_dict[site_id].append(response_time)

# calculate average
mean_response_times = {site_id: mean(pings) for site_id, pings in log_dict.items()}
num_responses = {site_id: len(pings) for site_id, pings in log_dict.items()}
```

Note also my `for` loop here. You can loop over a file handle to return the contents line by line.

Comment: cool, `defaultdict` seemed to solve it. I can loop over the list to get the info needed. Something like this:
```python
for id, pings in log_dict.items():
    print(id)
    print(len(pings))
    print(mean(pings))
```

Comment: also `response_time` had to changed to int as well before adding it to dictionary

Comment: thank you @Antimon for the solution